# How to subscribe to thingshadow updates using the AWS node.js sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

So I have a bunch of AWS IOT devices updating/reporting their state, but not sure how I can subscribe to the reported/accepted/delta states from my javsascript client.

I looked at the AWS sdk but don't see a method for subscribing to thing shadow events in the iot object.   I can use the aws-iot library but a bit confused about how to use AWS credentials for it (since it's not a device thing client).

In this use case, should I be using the AWS sdk or the AWS-IOT sdk?  What's the difference between the two.  If using the aws sdk how to subscribe to thingshadow events?  If using the AWS-IOT sdk, how can I use aws credentials rather than the certificate authentication?  I don't see it in the examples.

Comment: I don't think you can subscribe to a shadow event. Use the AWS-IOT within the thing to upload to AWS securely, and use a Rule to place the information in a place you can later pull from ( like DynamoDB ). Use the regular SDK to pull the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've got this approach to work.

```
Device -> Updates Thing Shadow data
Device -> Sends message to a generic topic with "Thing" id

API -> Listens to the generic topic
API -> Parses message that comes in to the generic topic with "Thing" id
API -> Uses AWS SDK  (AWS IOT Data class) to get the specific "Thing" shadow data
```

That's how I've been able to make the round through code.  I'm welcoming more updates as I go through and try to architect a better way.

Hope this helps.

-kev

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look for this documentation, maybe it can help you:

[https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/fd0807e20a0d79c721cfb3b85622392f0c65e7e1/examples/browser/mqtt-explorer/index.js)

When you publish something to a thingShadow, and the the state got accepted, you can subscribe to it in the channel '$aws/things//shadow/get/accepted'.

To subscribe to this channel, you can use the subscribe method from the device.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
    region: AWS.config.region,
    host:AWSConfiguration.host,
    clientId: clientId,
    protocol: 'wss',
    maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
    debug: true,
    acessKeyId: '',
    secretKey: '',
    sessionToken: ''
  });

device.subscribe('$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/get/accepted');
```

If you're confused or if you need informations about credentials,look this example:

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/fd0807e20a0d79c721cfb3b85622392f0c65e7e1/examples/browser/mqtt-explorer/index.js

The configurations files are in the same documentation.

Hope it helps.